# Day of week Android

Tags: java, android

I have day of week. And 2 buttons, I just need to set next day and previous on click

```
switch (dayOfWeek) {

    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        
        text1.setText("some text for MONDAY"); 

        break;

    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        text1.setText("some Text for TU");

        break;
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
        text1.setText("WEn");

        break;
    case Calendar.THURSDAY:
        text1.setText("TH");
        
    etc..
```

And Buttons

```
btnPlus.setOnClick...{
//from case1 to case2, from case2 to case3 etc

}
btnMnius.setOnCli..{
//from case1 to case7

}
```

I need a loop something like this http://www.java-examples.com/display-day-week-using-java-calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understand You the right way, it must be something like this:

Create a method like this:

```
 private void setDay(boolean dayIncrement){

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //get an instance of Calenar
      int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); //get the current day

switch (dayOfWeek) {

         //if it is monday....
case Calendar.MONDAY:

    text1.setText("some text for MONDAY");

    //if the plus button is pressed, the boolean dayIncrement is true
    if(dayIncrement==true){

         //then set the day of Calendar to the next day
         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.TUESDAY);

    //if the minus button is pressed, the boolean dayIncrement is false
    }else{

         //then set the day of Calendar to the previous day
         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
     } 

    break;

case Calendar.TUESDAY:
    text1.setText("some Text for TU");

    if(dayIncrement==true){

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.WEDNESDAY);

    }else{

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.MONDAY);
     }

    break;

case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
    text1.setText("WEn");

    if(dayIncrement==true){

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.THURSDAY);

    }else{

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.TUESDAY);
     }

    break;

case Calendar.THURSDAY:
    text1.setText("TH");

    if(dayIncrement==true){

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.WEDNESDAY);

    }else{

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);
     }

    break;

case Calendar.FRIDAY:
    text1.setText("Fri");

    if(dayIncrement==true){

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.THURSDAY);

    }else{

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SATURDAY);
     }
    break;

case Calendar.SATURDAY:
    text1.setText("SAT");

     if(dayIncrement==true){

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);

    }else{

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
     }
    break;

case Calendar.SUNDAY:
    text1.setText("SAN");

    if(dayIncrement==true){

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.THURSDAY);

    }else{

         cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.MONDAY);
     }
    break;
   }
}
```

and call this method inside the button click

```
     yourPlusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v){

                    setDay(true);
              }

      });



       yourMinusButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v){

                    setDay(false);
              }

      });
```

Comment: Thx for answer man. But i dont understand your code.
I want simple put some staf for all days and on button+ to see next day and data for next day. on button-  to se prev day

Comment: Thx man for your time thx a lot. i try the code before and it doesnt work now i will try this. thx again

Comment: maybe it helps if You just post Your Activity where You do Your stuff..

Comment: senad.bajra@gmail.com
please send me email and i will send my code thx